# How to make an Android phone as bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have 2 Android Phones, and I want to connect them together via bluetooth, and make one of them a bluetooth headset.

So, my question is how to program the second phone to change its role profile to "Bluetooth Headset" when establishing the connection ?

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163453/how-to-make-android-phone-as-a-bluetooth-headset) but my question is a little bit different

Thank for any advice or idea :)

Comment: I had posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873447/2437881), I hope to help you

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* on Android. At least using the built-in Bluetooth [`A2DP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) profile.

Your phone will only act as a transmitter *(source)*, not a receiver *(sink)*.

Please look at these two answers I gave on why this is not possible :

> - [Is it possible to send/receive voice from PC to Android device over Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818704/is-it-possible-to-send-receive-voice-from-pc-to-android-device-over-bluetooth/15821988#15821988)
> - [Receive audio via Bluetooth in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557933/receive-audio-via-bluetooth-in-android/15559902#15559902)

You can, on the other hand, develop two apps each acting as a *client/server* using your own protocol. The server could be streaming audio content to the client via Bluetooth for instance.

Another way to consider this, since using an Android device as an `A2DP sink` is not feasible on every phone, is building these two apps using your wifi connection. It could be much more rapid and the sound sound be of a much better quality.