# How to stream audio from one Android device to another Android device Via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, android-bluetooth, a2dp

Is it possible to stream audio over bluetooth? During my research I found that is it only possible using `A2DP(Advanced Audio Distribution Profile)`. And does every android device support A2DP? If not, is it possible to stream audio between two android devices using bluetooth? Please help me understand this.

I've looked through the following links:

- [Receive audio via Bluetooth in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559902/1405983),
- [Google confirms bluetooth audio streaming fix for next version of Android 4.2](http://www.talkandroid.com/147967-google-confirms-bluetooth-audio-streaming-fix-for-next-version-of-android-4-2/)
- [How can I stream audio from another device via Bluetooth?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41486/16851)

Comment: 1. Almost every device supports A2DP, A2DP and HFP(Handsfree) profile are the basic profiles which phone needs. 2. Android 4.2.1 had audio streaming issues over bluetooth, it was a choppy audio which got fixed as per google in latest release. 3. Most of the people earlier had tried on bluez (open source bluetooth)stack but from JB onwards ,bluez is replaced by broadcomm stack.  You need to implement audio sink profile in the phone. Audio streaming between 2 devices can be possible using Alljoyn, check [link](https://www.alljoyn.org/about/core-services)

Comment: Thank you for that link @ashish. I am go through that. And will let you know what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: Does the audio need to be streamed via Bluetooth? What about using [WiFi-Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)? This would actually give you more flexibility and features.

Comment: @BigMacAttack thank you for reply. But I need streamed via Bluetooth.

Comment: @Prince: How about your progression? Does it work?

Comment: @user8264 Actually later i leave with this requirements, client puts it on hold.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it possible to stream audio over Bluetooth?

Below sort of thread says its possibility that streaming audio over Bluetooth is possible between devices but there was question mark on its success rates till Google official announced that [*We have fixed the a2dp streaming stutter problem on N7. The next release should have the fix.
Sorry about the problem.*](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39633#c443)

[Fix for poor A2DP quality on 4.2.2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2184333)

[Bluetooth sound quality suffer after upgrade to 4.2 with Galaxy Nexus](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39632#c158)

[Android 4.3 Bluetooth Audio Quality Fix for Nexus 7 Flo](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=44756446)

> And does every android device support A2DP?

Support compatibility is mention on [Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html) that its added from `API Level-11 with appropriate features.` But I came across [XDA tread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=649059) where OP mention problem in `Android 2.1`,means its also support in previous api levels but OP facing issues.

Hope it make sense to understand  and I would like to recommend to refer [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/index.php) to get more information about A2DP compatibility and its sucess.

Answer (score 1):

I my opinion, if A2DP doesn't work properly, we'd better move to lower layer, and we can create a basic stream which can be used for sending any form of date. I succeed in sending byte stream via Bluetooth between J2ME devices.

If install an app in both devices is acceptable, I've sample codes to create a Bluetooth server and a client to communicate with each other via socket, once the socket is established, you can send you audio stream :)

here are some core codes:

1) server device:

```
// you can generate your own UUID and use it as an port to eatablish a socket
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("20687DAD-B023-F19E-2F60-A135554CC3FD")

BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID);
```

now you have the serverSocket, just use it as an ordinary ServerSocket:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

and then you can get `InputStream` and `OutputStream` from this `BluetoothSocket` and send audio stream just like `HttpConnection`

2) client device:

assume you already got the `BluetoothDevice`

```
// you should implement the method getBlutoothDevice
BluetoothDevice device = getBluetoothDevice();
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
```

Comment: It should be noted that normal A2DP is streamed over L2CAP which has a much larger payload size than an RFCOMM packet. Streaming over RFCOMM will result in poor audio quality due to the smaller payload size and additional layer involved

Answer (score 1):

You can also stream audio over a basic SCO connection which is not dependent on any profile. However, be aware that A2DP is a profile that was developed specifically for streaming music. So any implementation that you make yourself will suffer in quality compared to A2DP.

Unless you are streaming music to a device which does not support A2DP, I would certainly use A2DP. Really your only other option is to use a SCO link.

Answer (score -1):

Try using following code snippet:

```
    public class AudioStream extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String url = "http://www.example.mp3";
  MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  try {
   mp.setDataSource(url);
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mp.prepare();
   mp.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.i("Exception", "Exception in streaming = " + e);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's really hard to do that. But I did a lot of research and got a way. Has several delay, connection and root problems, but apparently works. For this you will need to have the "AirAudio" application installed on the server and the "AllConnect" receiver. Then you open AirAudio on the home screen and then open AllConnect, press on your device, then on sources and choose the server, then choose the streaming mp3. The problem is that the delay is very large and another defect is that to transmit only the sound of the system of the android server you should have root on the phone ... I also tried the receiver of the streaming being the VLC, was less delayed but still So it's uncomfortable.