# How to setup device as a bluetooth headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

Let us suppose we have a two devices with Android:

1. Custom android device with microphone, speaker, bluetooth and without GSM part.
2. Android smartphone (like a Nexus 5 or SGS4).

We need to make calls programmatically from first device through second via Bluetooth. What we are need to do to implementing it? Setup first device as headset? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

One device as server, one device as client.

Comment: Do you suggest to implement my own system for all calling process? But why? As I know Android has built-in support for that. May be I just need to activate headset mode in OS?

Comment: You need to make calls **programmatically**, right? Well, you need objects of bluetooth's classes. Do I understand your problem at all?

Comment: Yes, I need to initiate calls programmatically. And you are right, I need to implement server-client interaction for that. But what about sound? Sure, I can build my own system for this, grabbing sound from microphones and send it by Bluetooth with my own protocol. But I think that is very hard and I think here is exists more easy way to do it. So may be I just need to change some config file in OS for voice trnasferring in this case?

Comment: No, you need to implement it. Either you can find a library for it. Also try look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20222491/2159780

Comment: Thank you for answers and links. But how it working on car devices? When I call from my car device via my smartphone I didn't install some software. I just connect it and calling.