# Is it possible to redirect bluetooth from a TV to hearing aids?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Imagine using a hdmi splitter, to a raspberry Pi, or somehow to arduino. Grab the audio and send out via bluetooth.
I want to be able to pair my bluetooth hearing aids to the source and listen to TV independently of others listening to the tv via speakers or sound bar.

Hearing aids can pair to my android phone perfectly so i'm hoping to be able to pair to another source which is playing from another input.
Any help greatly appreciated

Still at the project discovery stage. Is it even possible.

Will use android studio, or whatever IDE is available. I can use java, javascript, php, html ... hopefully something works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the audio is no problem, you can use one on the many (and cheap) Bluetooth Transmitter / Receiver with 3.5mm audio jack. You can configure those devices to either send or receive signals, it this case it will redirect audio from the audio jack to bluetooth. The thing that is more tricky is determine which bluetooth you want to use (BTLE or older). Bluetooth Low Energy can be a little bit challenging to work with if you're an inexperienced one with this specific protocol. In android studio surely someone have created an app for that.
The following suggests how to use 2 android phones: [BLE audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159457/bluetooth-audio-streaming-between-android-devices)

Once you've gathered the audio data from the transmitter you only have to redirect it to your hearing aid device.
Hope I've gave you an idea

Comment: There's actually no development work to be done here - the question appears to be an off-topic usage question.  And there would be no choice of scheme, because the hearing aids use whatever scheme they use...