# Stream audio from microphone via bluetooth to another iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, bluetooth

I am trying to take incoming microphone audio and stream it to another iPhone. Basically a phone call but via bluetooth. I have the audio coming in via `AVAudioRecorder`:

```
func startRecording() {
    audioRecorder = nil
    let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, error: nil)

    var recordSettings:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: 10)
    recordSettings.setObject(NSNumber(integerLiteral: kAudioFormatLinearPCM), forKey: AVFormatIDKey)
    recordSettings.setObject(NSNumber(float: 44100.0), forKey: AVSampleRateKey)
    recordSettings.setObject(NSNumber(int: 2), forKey: AVNumberOfChannelsKey)
    recordSettings.setObject(NSNumber(int: 16), forKey: AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey)
    recordSettings.setObject(NSNumber(bool: false), forKey: AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey)
    recordSettings.setObject(NSNumber(bool: false), forKey: AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey)

    soundPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("record.caf")
    refURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath as String)
    var error:NSError?

    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: refURL, settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: &error)

    if audioRecorder.prepareToRecord() == true {
        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.record()
    } else {
        println(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Then I tried using `StreamReader` from [HERE - StreamReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581517/read-a-file-url-line-by-line-in-swift) from @martin-r

Using:

```
if let aStreamReader = StreamReader(path: documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("record.caf")) {
                while let line = aStreamReader.nextLine() {
                    let dataz = line.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    println (line)
```

Then send the data to another device using:

```
self.appDelegate.mpcDelegate.session.sendData(data: NSData!, toPeers: [AnyObject]!, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode, error: NSErrorPointer )
```

I convert line to NSData, then using a dispatch_after 0.5 seconds running constantly, I send it to another device via bluetooth.

It does not seem to work and I don't think this is a practical way of doing it. I have done numerous searches and haven't seen much on streaming data via bluetooth. The key word streaming (understandably) sends me to pages about server streaming.

My question is, how can I take audio from a microphone and send it to another iPhone via bluetooth? I have the bluetooth part all set up and it works great. My question is very similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789394/how-to-stream-audio-from-one-android-device-to-another-android-device-via-blueto) except with iPhones and Swift - I want to have a phone call via bluetooth.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which part isn't working? The audio capture or the data transmission? Break your problem into capture, transmission, and then conversion back to audio. I did some searching and found there are (complicated) ways of capturing streaming audio into NSData. Buffer the data and then stream it to your peers with MCSession startStreamWithName. Assuming that you want minimal latency so don't bother writing to a file and reading it back out.

Comment: Ok, so MCSession, I will give that a shot now. Yes, my issue is with the transmission. Got the recording going, got the transmission part, but the transmission doesn't send till after the full phrase is recorded. So you hold the button, talk, it records, then on button release, transmits.

Comment: Still not working. Can you give an example of a buffer in this situation?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I would love to speak with you about it, as I'm working on something very similar.

Comment: @iSkore have u did the app . is it working?

Comment: Hi, do you have a working sample code of this feature?

Comment: @iSkore could you please provide the git URL of sample code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To simultaneously record and redirect output you need to use the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute`.

Here's the link to the categories list:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories

If all else fails you can use a pre-made solution:
http://audiob.us

It has an API that lets you integrate audio streaming from one app to another:
https://developer.audiob.us/

It supports multiple output endpoints.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Multiple outputs via bluetooth? As in can I stream across bluetooth.

Comment: From one iPhone to another? (both using the same app)

Comment: @iSkore did you ever find out if you could stream from one phone to another using the same app?

Comment: @ijsnow, yes I did, a few people have asked me so far so I will post snippets on gist or release it to github and comment the link here. Thank you.

Comment: Ever get around to those snippets?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you have a working sample code of this feature?