# The sound quality of a2dp sink on android is terrible. How could I fix it?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I got lots of help in this site. and I worked to patch Jelly bean Android for making it as a sink on Bluetooth.
[How To Modify Android's Bluetooth Stack to Enable A2dp Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104611/how-to-modify-androids-bluetooth-stack-to-enable-a2dp-sink)

SNK works! but sound quality is bad!
There are lots of noises like sound distortion.
You can hear sound by click link : http://me2.do/5yLIflcx
password is 1111.

How could I make it good?

please, give me any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I listened to the audio file.
The sound doesn't seem to drop or click, so that probably rules out Wi-Fi/BT coexistence problems and bandwidth problems.
An educated guess is that this has to do with the SBC implementation.

Also, if you place the mic and the audiosource in an isolated sound booth (improvise one) you should be able to find out it the mic is actually to sensitive and is picking up all that noise.

Also, when the codecs used for speech is used for music, it sounds somewhat like this, so you might want to look in to the codec implementation.

It would be easier if you had access to a bluetooth sniffer or virtual sniffing, that would let you see the negotiations and see what codecs etc. is under use.

Could you do virtual sniffing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The product I've been developing does not have mic. and BT chip is connected directly main cpu(i.mx6) through I2S. The I2S ports are used for CPU and BT. Sound quality is good when I play music with player app. but BT is not good. Is there any way to set default SBC codec parameter? for example, LOUDNESS -> SNR

Comment: You can find a SBC decoder from Broadcom in Android L. 
details see http://blog.csdn.net/wendell_gong/article/details/47950781