# Turn Android phone into Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

Let's assume we have a rooted Android OS on a device that supports Bluetooth. Can we build an app that advertises itself as a Bluetooth speaker via Bluetooth A2DP?

If that was possible, then any other device could pair / connect to our Bluetooth server app and stream any music / sound. This server app could then take the music stream and play it locally or even send it to other devices via Wi-Fi. This would theoretically enable a multi-room Bluetooth solution.

Any idea how to achieve this? Where would I start?

Comment: Didn't you just ask that same question a few minutes ago?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290511/how-to-make-an-android-phone-as-bluetooth-headset) and the other questions  it links to.

Comment: @323go no I did not. The other question was about 'abusing' Bluetooth to get access to the local system audio out without root rights. This one is about inter-device communication where the server is a rooted device that receives the Bluetooth audio from any other device nearby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a very good and detailed answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559902/977804).

Short Answer: Possible, but requires to modify the Android OS configuration and quite some low level NDK development to expose the `A2DP Sink` role as API to be used.

Thanks @BartPlatak for the pointer!

Comment: The answer is based on bluez which is not used in Android L. You can find detailed answer for Android L http://blog.csdn.net/wendell_gong/article/details/47950781.