# Use a bluetooth headset as a extended microphone for a camcorder using android phone

Tags: android, audio, microphone, headset

I'm trying to film a video with a camcorder.
However, the camcorder isn't support bluetooth microphone.
Fortunately, I think I found a way to do it, but I can not find good app to do it.
My plan is, use phone as a bluetooth receiver, and connect the audio port of the phone to the camcorder via cable.
I need:
an app that make the bluetooth headset as a default microphone of the system.
an app that make the sound from the bluetooth mic able to flow to the audio port.

I know about an app called "megaphone" in Apple store that makes sound from the phone's mic flows through to the phone's audio port.
But I can not use the bluetooth headset for it.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great App.  Start by installing Android Studio (http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) and then its about research...  Search around SO (or google) for any of the keywords that sound reasonable.  Look at the related questions (on the right panel) for other questions that have been asked with similar key words (you'll find tons of info)

Start a project, and ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: This was meant to be a comment, not an answer, but here's some more info to get you started  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163453/how-to-make-android-phone-as-a-bluetooth-headset?rq=1